# Get/Display nested subquery column names in final result

Tags: oracle

In below Oracle statement i am using subqueries to get my final records.

This query is working fine but i wanna make it more optimal. Here, In nested sub query (i.e. third para) I am getting avg, max and min. Whatever result i got in the nested sub query (i.e. third para) Again I am using those column names in second para query, again, I am using the same column name(avg, max and min) in first para query to display my final result. Is there any optimal way so that i can use column names(avg, max and min) directly in first query(first para query).

```
select suq1.class_id, course.name, suq1.max_score, suq1.min_score, suq1.avg_score 
from course,
(select class.course_id as course_id, subq.class_id as class_id, 
        subq.maximum_score as max_score, subq.minimum_score as min_score, 
        subq.Average_Score as avg_score 
  from 
       (select class_id, max(score) as maximum_score, min(score) as minimum_score, 
               avg(score) as Average_Score from grade  group by class_id) subq,     
  class where subq.class_id=class.class_id) suq1 
where suq1.course_id=course.course_id;
```

Comment: I just edited your code and (while doing so) tried to read and understand it, and I still don't see what it is supposed to do. Please explain in plain English what the tables are (table name, column names and data types, only the tables and the columns that are relevant to the problems) and what output you are trying to get from that - what is the logic, and what columns the output must have and what they represent / how they are calculated. Maybe that sounds like a lot of work, and maybe it is, but you are looking for free advice - you must do some of the work.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the answer is no because based on the query the grade table PK is class and the table does not include the course.  What the query does is basically for each course find all the classes and then calculate the min/max/agv grades per class which are then feed to the calculation for by course.
- -
If the GRADE table includes the course number you can skip reading the class table as long as you do not need to account for discontinued classes, which the above query does not.
- -
HTH -- Mark D Powell --

Comment: I prefer to hear the requirement from the OP. If what you describe is right (I thought so too), then: FIRST, the join should be done first and only then the min/max/avg (they only need to be done once); and taking the average of the average-per-class is not the same as taking the average of all grades in a course (because not all classes have the same number of grades). But I don't want to give an answer, and then find out that the OP's requirement was different, that is why I asked the OP for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

If class_id and course_id are primary key and name is unique, this query might work..
But, if you have huge data in those tables, this query might work too slow..

```
SELECT B.CLASS_ID, C.NAME, MAX(B.SCORE), MIN(B.SCORE), AVG(B.SCORE)
  FROM CLASS A, GRADE B, COURSE C
 WHERE A.CLASS_ID = B.CLASS_ID
   AND A.COURSE_ID = C.COURSE_ID
 GROUP BY B.CLASS_ID, C.NAME
```